# Can this closed form solution of AIC for OLS be applied to tree regressors?

Tags: regression, cart, aic, boosting

Gordon (2015, p. 201) has a simple clossed form solution for AIC in the framework of OLS

$$\text{AIC} = n\log\left(\frac{SSE}{n}\right) + 2k$$

where SSE is the standard $SSE = \sum_i(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2$, n is the number of observations and k is the number of predictors (features).

**Can this formula also be applied to tree regressors like random forest or gradient boosted trees?**

I appreciate tree regressors are non-parametric and are not computed in the same framework as OLS, but the terms of the AIC formula above are relatively easy to calculate so it would be nice if it was transferrable.

Comment: $k$ is the number of estimated parameters, not the number of features. It is unclear how many parameters a decision tree estimates.